# How to change a transition duration with a button?

Tags: image, animation, radio-button, css-transitions, duration

hi, i have this code which works well, but i still need to control the speed of the animation via a radio button. So i need to replace 0.5s

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

with a variable, but i'm not sure how to implement it, either in javascript and in the button to declare the variable's value.
Any suggestion is very appreciated.
Thanks.

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('panner01').onclick = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('panpos01'),
    deg = 30;
div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';     

}

document.getElementById('panner02').onclick = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('panpos01'),
    deg =  60;
div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';     

}

document.getElementById('panner03').onclick = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('panpos01'),
    deg =  90;
div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';     

}
```

CSS

```
#panpos01 {
position:relative; 
height: 200px; 
width: 200px; 
margin: 30px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="panimageloc01"><img id="panpos01" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17392-200.png"></div>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="panner01" value="1"> 1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="panner02" value="2"> 2
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="panner03" value="3"> 3
</form>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnhope/h6pargLt/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the property transitionDuration

```js
document.getElementById('panner01').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('panpos01'),
    deg = 30;
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transitionDuration = '1.5s';

}

document.getElementById('panner02').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('panpos01'),
    deg = 60;
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transitionDuration = '0.5s';

}

document.getElementById('panner03').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('panpos01'),
    deg = 90;
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transitionDuration = '5s';

}
```

```css
#panpos01 {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="panimageloc01"><img id="panpos01" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/17392-200.png"></div>

<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="panner01" value="1"> 1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="panner02" value="2"> 2
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="panner03" value="3"> 3
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Vals, i appreciate. now it's the rotation button that decides the speed. My problem is that i should decide the speed from another set of radio buttons. Buttons 1 2 3 set the position, but buttons A B C set the speed.

Comment: Just duplicate your code for the other buttons, and set only the new part there ....